# Mount rsnapshot directory via NFS for non-root access

Tags: mount, nfs, rsnapshot

I'm trying to make my rsnapshot-backups available to non-root users on a Ubuntu server. There is a step-by-step instruction in the [rsnapshot HOWTO](http://www.rsnapshot.org/howto/1.2/rsnapshot-HOWTO.en.html#restoring_backups), which I think I've followed to the letter.

The HOWTO tells me to create the directories /.private/.snapshots/ (backup folder) and /.snapshots/ (mount point).

> In /etc/exports, add /.private/.snapshots/ as a read only NFS export:
>
> ```
> /.private/.snapshots/  127.0.0.1(ro,no_root_squash)
> ```
>
> In /etc/fstab,
>   mount /.private/.snapshots/ read-only under /.snapshots/
>
> ```
> localhost:/.private/.snapshots/   /.snapshots/   nfs    ro   0 0
> ```

However, when I issue the command:

```
mount /.snapshots/
```

I get this error message:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting localhost:/.private/.snapshots/
```

The package nfs-kernel-server is installed and I restarted it after editing /etc/exports.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure why but if you force it to NFS version 3 it should work:

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=3 localhost:/.private/.snapshots/   /.snapshots
```

The corresponding line for your fstab file would be

```
localhost:/.private/.snapshots  /.snapshots     nfs ro,vers=3,auto      0   0
```